# Running a power shell script in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-workflow, runbook

Hi there I'm new to running powershell scripts in azure and looking for the best guidance ?

I have created a powershell script to locate running machines in a resource group and output to a text file,

what would be the best approach to schedule this script to run autonomously in azure ?

Script below:

```
#Login-AzureRmAccount 
#$sub = Get-AzureRmSubscription | Out-GridView -PassThru | Set-AzureRmContext

$path="dcsppomsstorage.blob.core.windows.net/dcsvmpowerstate/activeserver1.txt"
function SPWservers {

[string]$ResourceGroupName = "*DCS-PP*"


$VMresourcegroups = (Get-AzureRmResourceGroup).Where({$_.ResourceGroupName -like $ResourceGroupName})
foreach($VMresourcegroup in $VMresourcegroups){
$vms=Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $VMresourcegroup.ResourceGroupName
foreach ($vm in $vms)
{

$Status = (get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName $VMresourcegroup.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status).Statuses

Write "powerstate for $($vm.Name) is $($Status[1].DisplayStatus)" | Format-Table $vm.Name, $Status[1].DisplayStatus -GroupBy $vm.name

}
}
}




SPWservers| out-file $path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bruno Faria said, we can use Azure Automation to do that.

But for now, we can't save the runbook job's output to Azure storage blob direct.

As a workaround, we can check the output in Azure portal.
Script like this:

```
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint
function SPWservers {
[string]$ResourceGroupName = "vms"
$VMresourcegroups = (Get-AzureRmResourceGroup).Where({$_.ResourceGroupName -like $ResourceGroupName})
foreach($VMresourcegroup in $VMresourcegroups){
$vms=Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $VMresourcegroup.ResourceGroupName
foreach ($vm in $vms)
{

$Status = (get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName $VMresourcegroup.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status).Statuses

Write "powerstate for $($vm.Name) is $($Status[1].DisplayStatus)" | Format-Table $vm.Name, $Status[1].DisplayStatus -GroupBy $vm.name

}
}
}

SPWservers| write-output
```

After this runbook job completed, we can find the **output** here:

[image]

About Azure runbook **schedules**, we can set it here:

[image]

More information about scheduling a runbook in Azure automation, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-schedules).

Comment: Extremely helpful, yes thank you very much!, i now have an approach to work from.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the **PowerShell runbook** in **Azure Automation** as the best guidance to your problem.

> **PowerShell runbooks**
>
> PowerShell runbooks are based on Windows PowerShell. You directly edit
>   the code of the runbook using the text editor in the Azure portal. You
>   can also use any offline text editor and import the runbook into Azure
>   Automation. Advantages
>
> Implement all complex logic with PowerShell code without the
>   additional complexities of PowerShell Workflow. Runbook starts faster
>   than PowerShell Workflow runbooks since it doesn't need to be compiled
>   before running.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types#powershell-runbooks

You can schedule your PowerShell runbook to run at the time and frequency which you desire.

In addition, the pricing for Azure Automation is FREE if you are using the Free Tier and your total job run time is under 500 minutes per month. If you don't have a lot of VMs and your job frequency is not very frequent, most likely you are able to get your jobs done for free in Azure.

Here's a good tutorial to get started with [PowerShell runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell).

Comment: @BenAhm If this answer has been helpful to you and you appreciate my effort, pleas kindly mark this as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Automation is what you are looking for. It's easy to use and works great. Besides that, you can run up to 500min of scripting on the free tier. More info on the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-offering-get-started

If for some reason you want to explore other options, there's also Azure Functions and Azure Web Jobs.

**Azure Functions**:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/02/24/using-powershell-modules-in-azure-functions/

**Web Jobs**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs

Comment: Extremely helpful !, since i'm trying to also Output the script to an Azure Storage Account / Blob Container, what approach would you recommend ?

Comment: Any of those work, but I'd stick with Azure Automation. Just make sure you have AzureRM.Storage in your list of Modules to be able to use it in your Automation RunBooks.